# How can I always return 3 values in this stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have an association table. The rows look something like: `id, objectID, thingID`.

I need a stored procedure to perform a select statement that will return 3 values:

```
item1ID, item2ID, item3ID
```

So the query will look something like:

```
SELECT TOP 3 objectID WHERE thingID = 7 -- (or something)
```

There may not always be three rows returned, however.

**What would the stored proc look like that returned the rows as values, but zeroes for the remaining rows if 3 are not returned?**

examples:

**data**

- id: 1, objectID: 12, thingID: 2
- id: 2, objectID: 13, thingID: 2
- id: 3, objectID: 14, thingID: 3
- id: 4, objectID: 15, thingID: 3
- id: 5, objectID: 16, thingID: 3

**results where thingID = 2**

`item1ID: 12, item2ID: 13, item3ID: 0`

**results where thingID = 3**

`item1ID: 14, item2ID: 15, item3ID: 16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to other answers but using sql table variable instead of temp table.
SQL table variables are cleaned up when the proc completes.

```
create proc ReturnTop3
as
begin

    declare @returnTable as table (
        objectId int
    )

    declare @count int


    insert into @returnTable
        SELECT TOP 3 objectID WHERE thingID = 7

    set @count = (select COUNT(*) from @returnTable)

    while (@count < 3)
        begin
            insert into @returnTable select 0
            select @count = @count + 1
        end

    select * from @returnTable
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp table and do it this way

```
    Create table #test (Id int);

    INSERT INTO #test
    SELECT TOP 3 objectID WHERE thingID = 7



    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(1) from #test) < 3
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #test 
        VALUES (0)
    END

    SELECT * FROM #test

    DROP TABLE #test
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this See fiddle

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed8ca/10

select TOP 3 ID, thing
from
(
select 0 as srt,ID,thing from tbl
where thing = 2
union all
select 1 as srt,0 as ID, 0 as thing
union all
select 2 as srt,0 as ID, 0 as thing
union all
select 3 as srt,0 as ID, 0 as thing
) as t
order by srt,thing
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @InputThingID INT = 2

DECLARE @ID AS INT, @ItemID1 AS INT = 0, @ItemID2 AS INT = 0, @ItemID3 AS Int = 0
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM MyTable WHERE ThingID=@InputThingID
SELECT TOP 1 @ID=ID, @ItemID1 = ObjectID FROM #Temp
DELETE FROM #Temp WHERE ID=@ID
SELECT TOP 1 @ID=ID, @ItemID2 = ObjectID FROM #Temp
DELETE FROM #Temp WHERE ID=@ID
SELECT TOP 1 @ID=ID, @ItemID3 = ObjectID FROM #Temp
DELETE FROM #Temp WHERE ID=@ID
SELECT @ItemID1 AS ItemID1, @ItemID2 AS ItemID2, @ItemID3 AS ItemID3
DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be the nicest and most universal, but probably also most difficult solution. The aggregation MAX function is needed, but doesn't affect the result.

```
SELECT [1] AS Item1ID,[2] AS Item2ID, [3] AS Item3ID FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
     OVER(order by id) rownum,objectId FROM data where thingId = 3) AS rows
    PIVOT(
    MAX(objectId)
    FOR rownum IN ([1],[2],[3])
    ) as piv
```